# Count values in multiple columns based on ranges in first column

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a  7 different columns with various attributes & 500 rows with corresponding values for these attributes [Numbers,texts,YES/No etc]..Example only 2 column with values shown.

1st column have range & rest 6 have values need to be counted based on the ranges.

Column 1 is called level ,  I have levels from 1 to 7....this will repeat for next groups.

Level 1 is main level & remaining levels [2 to 7] are sub levels. Need to find missing value counts for this group and subsequent groups.

PS: this is for a Bill OF material [BOM]

example

```
   Level Number Description
-   1   6586    ABC
    2   6579    XYZ
    3   6689    
    3   7854    123
    4   6011    GHF
G1  4   OOPO    YUI
    4   5589    OIK
    5   2132    
    6   4178    BUY
-   7   7145    CRI
*   1   8245    WES
    2   6666    RED
    3   1025    TRY
G2  3   9898    UIO
    4   4567    POL
    5   1234    WIP
    6   987     III
*   7   7787    RTE
+   1   6652    WED
    2   5425    
    3   9899    TRY
G3  3   6452    OOP
    4   3452    POE
    5   7890    
    6           LLK
+   7   8889    RET
```

Result expected [Aim is to find count of missing/wrong values]

```
Main ITEM      Number Description
    G1           1       3     [1 text in number column,2 blank/1 number in Dsecr column]
    G2           0       0     [ 0 error , as both columns filled proeprly]
    G3           1       2     [1 blank in Number column,2 blanks in Descr. column]


   Name & description corresponding to level 1 are always constant.
```

To make things bit more clear...

If i use MATCH function with lookupvalue ABC it will give position 3 & MATCH function for WES will give posiiton 9. Based on this range ,Row 3 to row 8,[Row 9 will start of anotther range] need count of blanks or texts for NUMBER,Count of blanks for DESCRIPTION and some other attributes which i have not included here.

ABC is a group with 2 to 7 sub levels

```
    1      6586     ABC
    2      6579     XYZ
    3      6689       
    3      7854     123
    4      6011     GHF
    4      OOPO     YUI
    4      5589     OIK
    5      2132     
    6      4178     BUY
    7      7145     CRI
```

WES is a group with next 2 to 7 sub levels

```
1      8245     WES
2      6666     RED
3      1025     TRY 
3      9898     UIO
4      4567     POL
5      1234     WIP
6      0987     III
7      7787     RTE
```

WED is next group

```
    1      6652     WED
    2      5425     
    3      9899    TRY
    3      6452     OOP
    4      3452     POE
    5      7890     
    6               LLK
    7      8889     RET
```

Comment: A picture with the results that you're looking for that goes along would help.

Comment: You list three columns (Level, Number, and Description), yet you say you want to count on "Name"?  That's not even in your example. Also, "main item" isn't described usefully enough.

Comment: @Tony,Sorry Number = Name.

Comment: Please explain discrepancy:  ABC -- Text in number column counts as error; WED -- Text in number column NOT counted as error

Comment: will there be "groups" without main items?

Comment: @Ron.its a mistake any text in number coloumn is a error.Will update the table

Comment: @bf2020,there will not be any groups without main items.This is an assembly & subassembly.[Imagine a Car Engine connecting Rod assembly,its main item here,different parts of connecting rods are sub levels.

Answer (score 0):

In cell D2 type `=if(A2="","",if(A2=1,C2,C1))`  This will associate main level name with all subgroups.

In cell E2 type `=if(A2="","",if(B2="",E1+1,E1))`  This will running count blanks in the numeric column for the main level

In cell F2 type `=if(A2="","",if(AND(B2>-1,B2<10000),F1+1,F1))`  This should running count non-numeric in the numeric column.

In cell G2 type `=if(A2="","",if(C2="",G1+1,G1))`  This should running count blanks in the description column

I don't have excel on this machine so this is untested.

Update for group sequence:
In cell H2 type `=if(A2="",H1+1,H1)`  This should generate a higher number sequence when the group changes.

In cell I2 type `="G"&H2`  This gets the H columns sequence and prefixes G by concatenation

If you paste all these functions down to the end of your data block, you should then be able to do a pivot table to "compress" everything into what you need as described in your specifications.  You can put the "I" and "D" columns in the row area of the pivot.  Double click each of these and for subtotals, select none.  The "E", "F" and "G" columns in the value area, double click each and pick "max".  Move the values to "columns" if the are vertically arranged.

Comment: thanks, but its not working.I need the group Level 1 to level 7 and count of all missing values together.Then same for next groups.

Comment: I guess it's better if groups are done based on level 1.Not all the groups will have same number fo levels [example one group may only have 6 levels].